# Can't use props when passing { t } (from i18n-react) to stateless component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, internationalization, i18next

I have the parent component that has the state:

```
class RecordEdit extends PureComponent {
    state = { 
        allRecordData: {},
        changelog: [
            {hello1: '1'},
            {hello2: '2'}
        ]
    }
```

It tries to render its child and pass the prop to it:

```
<div className='cards-container'>
    <ChangeHistory recordEditHistory={this.state.changelog} />
</div>
```

And the `ChangeHistory` component tries to map over the received prop to render a list of elements:

```
const ChangeHistoryCard = ({ t }, props) => (
  <CardOuterContainer recordEditHistory={props.recordEditHistory}>
    <h1>{t('История изменений')}</h1>
    {
      props.recordEditHistory &&
      props.recordEditHistory.map(item =>
        <p>{t('Последнее изменение')}: <span>[22.11.2018]</span></p>
      )
    }
  </CardOuterContainer>
);
export default withNamespaces()(ChangeHistoryCard);
```

For some reason, the component always thinks that the `recordEditHistory` prop is undefined. But if a click on it in the inspector, I can see that the value has been passed successfully:

[image: Props of ChangeHistoryCard]

I don't understand the problem. Can it be because I use **i18n** and using `withNamespaces` does something with props or...? I have to idea how to approach this problem.

**IMPORTANT:** { t } is from i18n-react, I use it to translate the interface to English and back. I tried removing it completely and it didn't help.

**EDIT**: I tried removing the `{ t }` method and removing `withNamesSpaces()` HOC from the export and it all works now. But now i can't use `i18n-react` in this component :(

Comment: What is the `{ t }` in the signature? Are you destructuring the params?

Comment: @Meir { t } is from i18n-react, I use it to translate the interface to English and back. I tried removing it completely and it didn't help.

Comment: Why don't you just import it the normal way and then just reference it? 

`import justPickAnyName from 'package-name';`

And then just use it like this: 

`justPickAnyName.t('message key');`

Comment: @Amsvartner yeah, I did it already, check out my answer below. I didn't know I could do that, first time using i18n, kinda went over the 'how-to' articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if you read the second edit, you would know that if I remove `i18n` from the component completely, it all seems to work.

That's great, but I really wanted the `i18n` to stay, so I found a better way:

Instead of passing `{ t }` to the component, you can `import 'i18next'` and call `t` as a method of that.

So this:

```
import { withNamespaces } from 'react-i18next';

const ChangeHistoryCard = ({ t }, props) => (
  <CardOuterContainer recordEditHistory={props.recordEditHistory}>
    <h1>{t('История изменений')}</h1>
    {
      props.recordEditHistory &&
      props.recordEditHistory.map(item =>
        <p>{t('Последнее изменение')}: <span>[22.11.2018]</span></p>
      )
    }
  </CardOuterContainer>
);
export default withNamespaces()(ChangeHistoryCard);
```

Becomes this:

```
import { withNamespaces } from 'react-i18next';
import i18next from 'i18next';

const ChangeHistoryCard = (props) => (
  <CardOuterContainer recordEditHistory={props.recordEditHistory}>
    <h1>{i18next.t('История изменений')}</h1>
    {
      props.recordEditHistory &&
      props.recordEditHistory.map(item =>
        <p>{i18next.t('Последнее изменение')}: <span>[22.11.2018]</span></p>
      )
    }
  </CardOuterContainer>
);


export default withNamespaces()(ChangeHistoryCard);
```

Thay way `i18n` stays in place, while props remain untouched and usable.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is with the component params:

`const ChangeHistoryCard = ({ t }, props) => ();`

Should be:

`const ChangeHistoryCard = (props) => ();`

Answer (score 1):

the signature of functional component only get **props**

> https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html
>
> Conceptually, components are like JavaScript functions. They accept arbitrary inputs (called “props”) and return React elements describing what should appear on the screen.

change

```
const ChangeHistoryCard = ({ t }, props) => ();
```

to

```
const ChangeHistoryCard = (props) => ();
```